# 16.04 Software and Updates: Update cache: Failed to download repository information

Tags: software-center, update-manager, repository

Software updater isn't working, saying it can't download repository information.

I've switched the download site to Main Server from a Canadian academic site.

Please explain like I'm five.

Boxes tell me this:

> The information about available software is out-of-date
>
> To install software and updates from newly added or changed sources, you have to reload the information about available software.
>
> Updating cache: Failed to download repository information:
>
> Details:
>
> ```
> W:The repository 'http://deb.bitmask.net/debian xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
> W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
> W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> E:Failed to fetch http://deb.bitmask.net/debian/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
> E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> ```

In terminal, `apt-secure` & `apt-secure manpage` give `command not found`.

I haven't been able to do Software Update for two days.  Yikes, I need patches re: Spectre and co.!

Comment: What you've posted indicates a problem with some third party repository. It doesn't look either main or Canadian, and may be it's a good idea to remove it. What is the output of  `sudo apt-get upddate`?

Answer (score 0):

You should restore the default repositories since deb.bitmask.net doesn't seem to be a public repository. I get **403 Forbidden** errors when I try to download.

There are instructions at [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)